# Ncover reporting exec with ccnet

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

i'm using the following exec for Ncover reportng

       "C:\Program Files\NCover\NCover.Console.exe"
        "C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit-console.exe"
            //w C:\CCNET\build\TA\BusinessLogic\"
           //x C:\CCNET\build\TA\BusinessLogic\Artifacts\ncover\bll-alog-coverage.xml"
          //l "C:\CCNET\build\TA\BusinessLogic\Artifacts\ncover\bll-alog-.log"
           " "C:\CCNET\build\TA\BusinessLogic\BLL\TA.BusinessLogic.TimeAttendance.AttendLog.Tests\bin\Debug\TA.BusinessLogic.TimeAttendance.AttendLog.Tests.exe "

and

C:\CCNET\build\TA\BusinessLogic\Artifacts\dao-coverage.xml

but after building ,Ncover in webdash board seems to be empty

Answer (score 2):

If you use exec task for ncover you will need to manually merge the ouput file from ncover as shown in http://docs.ncover.com/how-to/continuous-integration/cruisecontrol-net/

But did you try using the ncover tasks directly in ccnet instead of an exec task? see : http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/NCover+Reporting+Task and http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/NCover+Profiler+Task

You will also need to have the proper xsl script in your dashboard.config and ccservice.exe.config files.

Answer (score 0):

the new site for ccnet is http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet

ncover reporting task
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/NCover_Reporting_Task

ncover profiler task
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/NCover_Profiler_Task